# "Action 'microsoft.directory/appRoleAssignments/create' is not supported for Custom Role creation." Why?

Tags: azure-active-directory

I'm trying to create a custom directory role that will allow me to grant only the permission to create approle registrations to a service principal, scoped to a particular app registration. I'm using the following powershell script:

```
# Basic role information
$displayName = "Application Role Deployer"
$description = "Can assign API roles to Logic App service principals."
$templateId = (New-Guid).Guid

# Set of permissions to grant
$allowedResourceAction =
@(
    "microsoft.directory/appRoleAssignments/create"
)
$rolePermissions = @{'allowedResourceActions'= $allowedResourceAction}

# Create new custom admin role
$customAdmin = New-AzureADMSRoleDefinition -RolePermissions $rolePermissions -DisplayName $displayName -Description $description -TemplateId $templateId -IsEnabled $true
```

When I run this - and I am not a directory administrator anyway, so I expect this to fail with a permissions error - it instead produces the following error:

```
New-AzureADMSRoleDefinition : Error occurred while executing NewAzureADMSRoleDefinition 
Code: Request_BadRequest
Message: Action 'microsoft.directory/appRoleAssignments/create' is not supported for Custom Role creation.
InnerError:
  RequestId: 155482f0-3ebf-4840-bbe3-4e1691a61d9c
  DateTimeStamp: Wed, 10 Jun 2020 10:11:22 GMT
HttpStatusCode: BadRequest
HttpStatusDescription: Bad Request
HttpResponseStatus: Completed
At line:14 char:16
+ ... stomAdmin = New-AzureADMSRoleDefinition -RolePermissions $rolePermiss ...
+                 ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
    + CategoryInfo          : NotSpecified: (:) [New-AzureADMSRoleDefinition], ApiException
    + FullyQualifiedErrorId : Microsoft.Open.MSGraphBeta.Client.ApiException,Microsoft.Open.MSGraphBeta.PowerShell.NewAzureADMSRoleDefinition
```

Why is `Action 'microsoft.directory/appRoleAssignments/create' is not supported for Custom Role creation.`? It's a directory permission. Custom Directory roles take directory permissions. Why can't I use this one?

Answer (score 0):

Currently, only permissions for Application registrations are supported in custom roles. You can find the list of supported permissions [here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/active-directory/users-groups-roles/roles-custom-available-permissions).

Or you can just find them from **Azure Portal** -> **Azure Active Directory** -> **Roles and administrators** -> **+New custom role** -> **Permissions** tab.

That is why you get `'microsoft.directory/appRoleAssignments/create' is not supported for Custom Role creation`.